# replace multiple column values at the same time

Tags: replace, multiple-value

I would like to replace multiple column values at the same time in a dataframe. I would like to change 2 to 1, 1 to 2.

```
 data=data.frmae(store=c(122,323,254,435,654,342,234,344)
 ,cluster=c(2,2,2,1,1,3,3,3))
```

The problem in my code is after it changes 2 to 1 , it changes these 1's to 2.
Can I do it in dplyr or sth? Thank you
Desired data set below

```
store  cluster
122      1
323      1
254      1
435      2
654      2
342      3
234      3
344      3
```